# Performance issue using Merge in azure sql stored proc

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, merge, azure-sql-database

Problem: We are experiencing sql timeouts which we believe are attributed to a recent database change that changed db schema and implemented a new proc that handled deletion and insertion of rows into a table. This table is quite large with around 4.5 million rows(but only five columns,three of which can be null), and is indexed with a primary key made up of two columns (UserID, GroupID). Unfortunately our database guy is unavailable and we are kind of stuck in between a rock and a hard place.

Question: Is there anything in the following stored procedure that sticks out as being a performance issue or is incorrectly done?

inputs:

UserID

GroupIDs (list of unique identifiers)

UpdateAdminID (Unique identifier of user who initiated stored proc)

Expectations:

When calling this stored procedure the expectation is that a row for each groupID will be inserted into `UserGroups` where it does not exist already. Also if a row is found that has the UserID parameter and a GroupID that is not in the input list then it must be deleted.

Procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO





CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateUserGroups] (

      @UserID uniqueidentifier,
      @Groups IDs READONLY,
      @UpdateAdminID uniqueidentifier = NULL
      ) AS
BEGIN


DECLARE @EnforceUserGroupHeirarchy bit

DECLARE @ClientID uniqueidentifier
DECLARE @AttributeClientID uniqueidentifier
select @ClientID = clientid from users where userid=@userid

select @AttributeClientID=isnull(ParentClientID, ClientID)from clients where ClientID=@ClientID


select @EnforceUserGroupHeirarchy= value from v_clientpreferences where preferenceid=323 and clientid=@AttributeClientID


DECLARE @NumRows INT
SET @NumRows = 1

CREATE TABLE #AllGroups
(
    GroupID uniqueidentifier
)

insert into #AllGroups (GroupID) select id from @Groups

if @EnforceUserGroupHeirarchy = 1
BEGIN
    WHILE @NumRows>0
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #AllGroups (GroupID)
    (
    SELECT groupid from groups where (parentgroupid in (select groupid from #AllGroups)) and groupid not in (select groupid from #AllGroups)
    )
    SET @NumRows = ROWCOUNT_BIG()
    END
END


merge usergroups as T
USING (select @UserID as UserId, g.groupid as GroupId from #AllGroups g) as S
on (T.UserID = S.UserID and T.GroupID = S.GroupID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
THEN INSERT (UserID, GroupID, DateCreated, UpdateAdminID) VALUES(S.Userid,S.GroupID,GetDate(),@UpdateAdminID)
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE and T.UserID =@UserID
THEN DELETE;

END

GO
```

Edit: Fragmentation of indexes is less then 30 percent.

Edit2: EnforceGroupHirearchy looks at a group, and recursivly adds all children to `#AllGroups`.

Comment: Why do you make a WHILE ? I mean Did you need it?

Comment: I did not write this but I think I know why this was done. Each Group contains a reference to a lookup table that stores references to its children. it adds a groups children to a list and then ads the childrens' children to a list, until zero results.

Comment: Do you know what the previous version of the SP looked like? You could diff the two and assume that whatever is new is causing the problem. I agree with Beto is suspecting the while loop is the cause of the issue.

Comment: Everything is different from the previous workflow which included getting the list of GroupID's in code behind, but I was able to cut down the execution time by a factor of 4 by separating the merge into an update and a delete statement. I think that the while loop is not necessarily good, but also not the major performance hog.